# CNN to estimate a density map of an image, used to predict the object count

Tags: tensorflow, k-means, object-detection, python-3.x, opencv

I'm trying to count the number of objects (larvae in this case), from a video. The constraint is, I cannot use any ML model, nor can I train my dataset as there are no annotations available.

This being the overall goal, I first tried density map on all the frames from the video, and it gave me a very large prediction, i.e., the predicted value was of the order 1e7, when the larvae count is ~50.
On looking at density plots more closely, I notice the algorithm is counting objects which are not even larvae, so I thought let me narrow down the question to just one frame at the moment.
In the first frame, I look at applying the k-means cluster on the colours present in the image. Then after a lot of manipulation, I decide, it is top 20 colours expressed is something that I should look at.
After finding the right tolerance value for masking the image and manually deciding the colour which most closely align with the colour of the larvae, I apply density map on masked image for the colour of interest.

It now happens that the count is now of thee order 1e3, but still wrong.
When looking closely at the density maps, it is predicting/ counting the density of point objects and this is the reason for my issue.

I need help with two major things:

1. How to automatically choose the colour of larvae instead of manually choosing them?
2. How do I change the density map such that it doesn't count point objects, but give me a closer answer for my actual count.

For the 1st aspect, I am thinking, I take 1st from from the the (n,n+10) frames and check thee colours which have moved a lot, the ones which have major shift should be the colour of larvae, but I am not sure if this will work, nor am I sure on how to code this.

For the second I have no clue about it, and am hoping someone can help me out here.

The code for kmeans clustering that I'm using is:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create a video capture object
video_path = '/Users/dev.barbhaya9gmail.com/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-IITKanpur/Research/Nitin_Gupta/VID_20240129_182938.mp4'
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)

# Get the video properties
frame_width = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
frame_height = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))

# Process the first frame
ret, frame = cap.read()
if ret:
    # Reshape the frame to a 2D array of pixels and 3 color values (RGB)
    pixel_values = frame.reshape((-1, 3))

    # Convert to float
    pixel_values = np.float32(pixel_values)

    # Define criteria for K-means clustering
    criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 100, 0.2)

    # Number of clusters (colors) to detect
    k = 20  # Change this to 20 for top 20 colors

    # Perform K-means clustering
    _, labels, centers = cv2.kmeans(pixel_values, k, None, criteria, 10, cv2.KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS)

    # Convert back to 8-bit values
    centers = np.uint8(centers)

    # Get the top twenty dominant colors
    unique, counts = np.unique(labels, return_counts=True)
    top_twenty_indices = np.argsort(counts)[-20:][::-1]
    top_twenty_colors = centers[top_twenty_indices]

    # Create a masked frame for each of the top twenty dominant colors
    for i, color in enumerate(top_twenty_colors):
        # Define a threshold for color matching
        color_match_threshold = 20  # Adjust this threshold as needed

        # Create a mask for the current color
        mask = np.linalg.norm(frame - color, axis=-1) <= color_match_threshold

        # Create an image with only the current color present
        color_image = np.zeros_like(frame)
        color_image[mask] = frame[mask]
        
        # Extract pixels corresponding to the current color
        masked_pixels = frame[mask]

        # Calculate the histogram for the masked pixels (color distribution)
        hist, bins = np.histogram(masked_pixels, bins=np.arange(0, 257))

        # Create the histogram plot
        plt.figure(figsize=(5, 3))  # Adjust figure size as needed
        plt.plot(bins[:-1], hist)
        plt.title(f"Histogram for Color {i+1}")
        plt.xlabel("Pixel Intensity")
        plt.ylabel("Frequency")

        # Save the histogram plot as an image
        plt.savefig(f'color_{i+1}_histogram.png')
        plt.close()  # Close the plot figure

        # Convert the image to RGBA (with alpha channel)
        color_image_rgba = cv2.cvtColor(color_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)

        # Set the alpha channel to 0 for the background (black or transparent)
        color_image_rgba[~mask, 3] = 0  # Set alpha to 0 for background pixels

        # Save the image with the current color and transparent or black background
        cv2.imwrite(f'color_{i+1}.png', color_image_rgba)

    print("Images with individual colors among the top twenty colors saved.")

# Release the video capture object and close the OpenCV windows
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The code for density map is:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, Input
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.losses import MeanSquaredError
import cv2

# Create the density map estimation model
def create_density_map_model(input_shape):
    inputs = Input(shape=input_shape)
    x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(inputs)
    x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    density_map = Conv2D(1, (1, 1), activation='linear', padding='same')(x)
    model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=density_map)
    return model

# Load the image
image_path = 'color_17.png'
image = cv2.imread(image_path, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

# Extract the alpha channel from the image
alpha_channel = image[:, :, 3]

# Threshold the alpha channel to get a binary mask where non-transparent pixels are white (255) and transparent pixels are black (0)
_, binary_mask = cv2.threshold(alpha_channel, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# Get the height and width of the image
image_height, image_width = image.shape[:2]

# Create and compile the model
input_shape = (image_height, image_width, 1)
model = create_density_map_model(input_shape)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=MeanSquaredError())

# Preprocess the image
image_gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
image_normalized = image_gray / 255.0
image_input = np.expand_dims(image_normalized, axis=-1)
image_input = np.expand_dims(image_input, axis=0)

# Predict the density map for the image
predicted_density_map = model.predict(image_input)

# Reshape the predicted density map to match the shape of the image
predicted_density_map = np.reshape(predicted_density_map, (image_height, image_width, 1))

# Create a size factor map (assuming all pixels have the same size factor for simplicity)
size_factor_map = np.ones_like(predicted_density_map)

# Apply the size factor map to the predicted density map
predicted_density_map_filtered = predicted_density_map * size_factor_map

# Expand the dimensions of the binary mask to match the number of channels in the predicted density map
binary_mask_reshaped = np.expand_dims(binary_mask, axis=-1)

# Apply the binary mask to the filtered density map to only keep values where the image isn't transparent
predicted_density_map_filtered = predicted_density_map_filtered * (binary_mask_reshaped / 255.0)

## Apply the binary mask to the filtered density map to only keep values where the image isn't transparent
#predicted_density_map_filtered = predicted_density_map_filtered * (binary_mask / 255.0)

# Save the filtered density map as an image
cv2.imwrite('density_plot_filtered.jpg', (predicted_density_map_filtered * 255.0).astype(np.uint8))

# Calculate the number of larvae predicted from the filtered density map
num_larvae_predicted = int(np.sum(predicted_density_map_filtered))

# Print the number of larvae predicted
print(f"Number of larvae predicted: {num_larvae_predicted}")
```

The video that I used for the first code, i.e., the kmeans for identifying the top 20 expressed colours can be found here:
https://iitk-my.sharepoint.com/:v:/g/personal/abint21_iitk_ac_in/EexjUqun0pZFmzRTxTBHGFoB8ML2hX5iZ6luH9QVWpLjKA?e=mLQLfb

To add, the colour of interest when viewed with rgba palette looks like this:
[image]

The density plot for this image comes out as something like this:
[image]

I hope this information was helpful for making the details clear. Please let me know in case more details are needed.